# Dynamically setmaxLength on textarea compnent

Tags: reactjs

I create a `<Textarea>` component to use multiple times but I need to allow the maxLength to be set on the `return` side since they will have differen't requirements when they are deployed. How do I pass the `setmaxLength` to the component so that we can change it for each instance?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Textarea(props) {
  const [textAreaCount, settextAreaCount] = useState(0);
  const [maxLength, setmaxLength] = useState(0);

  const recalculate = (e) => {
    settextAreaCount(e.target.value.length);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <textarea
        type="text"
        maxLength={setmaxLength}
        onChange={recalculate}
      />
      <p>{textAreaCount}/5</p>
    </>
  );
}
export default Textarea;

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Textarea maxLength={10} />
      <Textarea maxLength={5} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the state hook in the parent component, then pass the getter and setter as props like so

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Textarea(props) {
  const [textAreaCount, settextAreaCount] = useState(0);
  const {maxLength, setmaxLength} = props;

  const recalculate = (e) => {
    settextAreaCount(e.target.value.length);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <textarea
        type="text"
        maxLength={maxLength}
        onChange={recalculate}
      />
      <p>{textAreaCount}/5</p>
    </>
  );
}
export default Textarea;

const App = (props) => {
  const [maxLen1, setMaxLen1] = useState(10);
  const [maxLen2, setMaxLen2] = useState(5);
  return (
    <>
      <Textarea maxLength={maxLen1} setMaxLen={setMaxLen1} />
      <Textarea maxLength={maxLen2} setMaxLen={setMaxLen2} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't think it needs setMaxLen

Comment: Yes, setMaxLen is only required if the Textarea component will be updating the maxLength.